# How to not duplicate opened site and send commands to already opened

Tags: javascript

I have one-page JS tool. When some event is fired, user got an e-mail. In it there is a link to my tool. But I do not wand to open new tab with duplicated tool to let user do smth. with fired event.
I want to redirect him from e-mail to already opened tab (if it exists, or simply open new) and set new data.

Like this: suppose user has tab with http://example.com/ opened, then he got an e-mail with link to http://example.com/?open=sometab_int_the_tool. In normal way, when user click on that link, he got duplicated tab with http://example.com/. But obviously, the better way is to open existed tab and send to it command to open some tab.

How can I do this?

Comment: Use the target attribute of a tag or window.open. A different target for each unique link

Comment: I can't do what I want with target or window.open. Because with this I need to hold another window that will be hold the link to desired window and handle requests

Comment: simple answer, you can't because you have **zero** control over what an email client does when a user clicks a link in an email